# React js Drag and Drop

Tags: reactjs, list, drag-and-drop

I have 2 list(left and right), so I just want move the item's list left to list right, so, my list left is:

```
const data = [
  { name: "Item A 1", checked: false, array: ['value 1', 'value 2']  },
  { name: "Item B 2", checked: false, array: ['value 1', 'value 2']  },
  { name: "Item C 3", checked: false, array: ['value 1', 'value 2']  },
  { name: "Item D 4", checked: false, array: ['value 1', 'value 2']  },
  { name: "Item E 5", checked: false, array: ['value 1', 'value 2']  },
  { name: "Item F 6", checked: false, array: ['value 1', 'value 2']  },
  { name: "Item G 7", checked: false, array: ['value 1', 'value 2']  },
  { name: "Item H 8", checked: false, array: ['value 1', 'value 2']  },
]
```

so, when It running I have something like:

[image]

so the issue that I'm getting is that when I move any item of list left to list right, the list right don't get the data:

I got this issue:
[image]

I was checking it but I don't know that's wrong, so, what's wrong? what can I do for get the object on mi list right???

I have the code on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-and-drop-2-list-n3kxsk?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go : [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-and-drop-2-list-forked-2j576g?file=/src/Item.js)

I changed :

```
const newLeftItems =
  source === "left"
    ? leftItems.filter((x) => x.name !== items.name)
    : leftItems.concat(items);
const newRightItems =
  source === "left"
    ? rightItems.concat(items)
    : rightItems.filter((x) => x.name !== items.name);
```

And

```
  if (dropResult) {
    props.addItemsToCart(props, item.source, dropResult);
    props.clearItemSelection();
  }
```

Comment: let me test it, please

Comment: yes, this is working, thanks!!!! take your points